# What can we say? Variance = Mean

Tags: probability, inequality

Let X be a random variable with mean and variance equal to $20$. What can you say about $P(0 < X< 40)$?

I've tried using chebyshev inequality. We now that $O<X<40$ can be written like $|X-20|< 20$.

Then using Chebyshev $P \{\ |X-20|<20|\}>1 - 20^2/20^2 = 0 $, which is obvius. Can somebody help me?

Comment: When using Chebyshev's inequality, you look at the spread from the mean in terms of the standard deviation (rather than the variance).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you might have substituted the values wrong (varience is 20 not standard deviation):

$$P(|X-\mu|\geq \varepsilon) \leq \frac{\sigma^2}{\varepsilon^2}$$
In your case we have to revert the inequalities so we obtain:

$$P(|X-\mu|\leq \varepsilon) \geq 1-\frac{\sigma^2}{\varepsilon^2}.$$

Substituting the values I got:

$$P(|X-20|\leq 20) \geq 1-\frac{20}{20^2} = 1-\frac{1}{20}=\frac{19}{20}=0.95.$$

This is giving a lot of information. It simply says that a random variable with mean $\mu$ and variability $\sigma$ can not be very far away from $\mu\pm \sigma^2$, this is a very wide used rule in statistics.

It might also be useful to take a quick Reading in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev's_inequality#Probabilistic_statement

Comment: Note that if $X$ is discrete RV you can have problems moving from the first to the second line - this is since there is a positive probability that $X-\mu=\pm \epsilon$

Comment: I don't know what I'm talking about because I'm not a statistician, but it seems to me that the expression $\mu\pm\sigma^2$ doesn't make sense dimensionally, you could be adding an area to a length. A typo, maybe?

Comment: Come on guys... out of your nitpicking I see you are not statisticians ;) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multidimensional_Chebyshev's_inequality

Comment: In any case it is clear in the context of the question that the dimension is one, the variance is $20$. Adding dimension would confuse him I think. I agree the discrete case is different, he can ask if he needs an explanation for that too